# performing arithmetic on variables set by while-read loop

Tags: bash, awk, while-loop, text-manipulation

I want to perform some arithmetic and floating point arithmetic operations on some variables that I read in from a `while` loop.  My code looks like this:

```sh
while read n p qlen slen len; do 

    random_var=$(( $qlen + 0 )) # gives all zeros, not saving qlen

    qcov=$(echo $len / $qlen | bc -l) #len and qlen are nothing, not working

    qcov=$( bc  <<< "scale=3; $len / $qlen" ) #same reason as above, not working

done < input_file.txt
```

I am pulling each line in `input_file.txt` and parsing the data into their respective variable names, `n`, `p`, `qlen`, `slen`, and `len`.  The input file `input_file.txt` looks like this:

```
test1 12.345 123 234 12
test2 23.456 345 678 43
test3 98.765 6537 874 346
...
```

The problem I am having is when I try to perform some arithmetic operation on any of the variables from the `read`.  I can `echo` the variables just fine, but as soon as I try to perform any kind of arithmetic manipulation, the values are nothing.  I suspect that they are not numerals to begin with, some sort of string type (?).  I've tried many integer and floating point arithmetic statements and can't seem to preserve the values in the variables.  `bc` commands, arithmetic expansion, `echo` piped into `bc`, the triple `<<<` for `bc`, all of these solutions I've found online do not work.

The most common errors I receive are:

- strings of nothing
- (system-in) error 1: parse error
- (system-in) error 2: parse error

I've thought about using an `awk` but I need to perform these operations on every line, and awk keeps going until the end of the file.  Is there still a way to do what I want using an `awk`? I don't really know.

If anyone has an answer or an alternative way to pull data out of the file, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

some fiddling around with the code has made me realize that everything in the `input_file.txt` is being saved into only the first variable `n`.  This is why the other variables are empty and why the echo of all the variables looked correct.

Any ideas why the values are not being saved into the correct variables?

Comment: Can you post the output of `file file.txt`. Note that `file` is the name of the command. Also is your file space or tab delimited?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I've updated the question to clarify what I meant by input file.

Comment: Impossible to answer if you don't tell us what's actually in the file.

Comment: Have you changed the value of `IFS`? Also, are those normal spaces between fields in the file (i.e. not nonbreaking spaces or something like that)?

Comment: @Justin: Please post exactly the code you are actually using. In your code, you don't output any variables, so you can not say that "the values are nothing" if you don't print them. Also, the wording of the error message, _parse error_, does not look as something coming from bash.

Comment: @Justin : Are the fields in the input file separated by space or by tab?

Comment: Your program contains a couple of common issues, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). Show a minimal representation of your real script that demonstrates why you need to use a shell loop for this instead of just doing it all in awk.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you really want to obtain. but it seems something like

```
awk '{print $5/$3}' input_file.txt 
0.097561
0.124638
0.0529295
```